# Force -Match Operator to Fail Expression

Tags: regex, powershell, match

I'm working on an expression to validate Active Directory user names. I'm doing that by creating a negated character class and telling it to look for anything not " / \ [ ] : ; | = , + * ? < >. The issue is when I use the -match operator it will match on characters that are technically valid like n or i, but I want the expression to fail the match because it also contained something like !

```
'!nv,@l|d?' -match  '[^"/\\\[\]:;|=,+\*\?<>!]+'
```

Comment: You need to list all the valid characters, which I presume includes letters and digits (`[^]["/\\:;|=,+*?<>!A-Za-z0-9]`).

Comment: This should also work and is a good example of how to write and expression to match and one to not match without using additional regex syntax like anchors. thanks for the reply!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Try the following:

```powershell
$username = '!nv,@l|d?'
$notValid = $username -match    '[]["/\\:;|=,+*?<>!]' 
$valid =    $username -notmatch '[]["/\\:;|=,+*?<>!]'
```

Characters to be treated as literals that are ordinarily regex metacharacters do *not* need special treatment inside a *character set* (`[...]`), with two exceptions:

- Literal `\` must still be escaped as `\\`
- `]` and `[` must be placed carefully at the *beginning* of the character set, so as not to be mistaken for the *delimiters* of the character set.

Character set `'[]["/\\:;|=,+*?<>!]'` is matched against *each and every* character in the input, given that the expression as a whole is not *anchored*, so there is no need for a quantifier such as `+`.

Conversely, with your character-class *negation* logic (`[^...]`) you would have had to *anchor the entire expression* (`^[^...]+$`) to achieve the desired result - i.e., ensure that the entire input is composed solely of non-forbidden characters.
Without the start-of-input (`^`) and end-of-input anchors (`$`), any run of *at least one* non-forbidden character would match, potentially yielding false positives, such as with your sample input.
While anchoring your negated character set with `^[^...]+$` to match the *entire* input would also work, it is less efficient.

Comment: fantastic explanation, thank you for taking the time to write this detailed reply. Adding an anchor will get me what I want. It's also good to know about the [] inside the character class. Regex isn't easy to explain, but you did a great job.